# How are varargs interpreted in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

Say I have these methods:

```
public void a(String string, Object ... objects) {
    //Code...
}

public void a(Object ... objects) {
    notNull("Some String", objects);
}
```

Will a call to the a method with only one parameter work? Or will the overloaded method with the string and the vararg take the array from the method with only a vararg as the first object in it's list(making it objects[0][...]) ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd like you to try it before asking the question.

Comment: Practice makes you perfect. Try yourself as you say.

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html "found via google search")

Comment: thx for voting down lol

Comment: The downvotes are because: you basically say "I wonder how this works", when you should say: "I have overloaded varargs method, wrote this code snippet [provide runnable code] and this overloaded method will be called and not the other one. Why is that?" Now that would be a question worthy of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, varargs is basically a syntax suger.

Instead of:

```
void myMethod(Object[] args) { ... }
// ...
myMethod(new Object[]{"foo",2,true});
```

You can write

```
void myMethod(Object... args) { ... }
/// ...
myMethod("foo",2,true);
```

And compiler will wrap it in an array for you. Read more [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2011/09/variable-argument-in-java5-varargs.html).

About your question, just write that code down and see what variation of your overloaded method will be called.